# should a parallel (gnu-)make not wait before linking until all its dependent object-files are "finished" (rather than "started" only)?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have multiple pattern rules to build various object files (multiple because they are assembly and c-sources and in different directories) and one single linking rule to linke them all together in the end; such as:

```
$(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o obj/%.o:$(DIR1)/%.s
        $(AS) .....

$(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o obj/%.o:$(DIR2)/%.s
        $(AS) .....

$(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o:%.c
        $(CC) .....

obj/%.o:$(DIR3)/%.c
        $(CC) .....

$(OUTPUT_FILE): $(OBJECT_FILES)
        $(LD) ....
```

(parallel make invocation)

this most of the times works perfect; but occasionally (don't exactly know when, maybe heavy load on the build server...) the linker cannot link since it does not "recognize" one of its object-files:
`obj/boot_init_dram.o: file not recognized: File truncated``

this object file in question is rather large (500kiB)

discussing this issue with a colleague, he meant that `$(LD)` considers any of its dependencies as fulfilled as soon as it "sees the file", i.e., when the file is started to be written to the filesystem...

questions:
Is this indeed the root-cause of my problem here, or maybe anything else?
- should make not wait until the file is "ready", meaning the according compile sub-task ended instead? make does know which dependencies need refreshing when building any particular target; would not be too hard to wait for those tasks to end before continuing with the current target, would it?

is there maybe a more elegant solution to this race-condition than compiling into a temporary object file and renaming it to the real name once it is ready?
- this should not be needed after all, if make would do it's job properly...
(such as a compiler option to not write partial object-files or such?)

(p.s. this is gmake 3.81 - updating is not an option; this is what yocto comes with...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your colleague is not correct.  Make doesn't consider a target complete until the recipe that builds that target exits.  Make doesn't track files appearing on the filesystem, it simply invokes a shell (or the equivalent) to run the recipe then waits for the recipe to be complete and the process to exit: if the exit code is 0 then make considers that the recipe succeeded.

Only after all the prerequisites for a target are complete (so their recipes have exited with a success code) will that target's recipe be invoked.

I can't explain the behavior you're seeing but it's not because make assumes a recipe is complete when the target file exists.  You can prove this to yourself by adding an `echo` command or similar into the recipe after the compilation is complete: you'll see that all those outputs appear before the link starts.

Comment: Maybe some caching issue then? e.g. the compile task already ended thus triggering the link target, but some filesystem cache has not really written the object file to the hard-disk when the linker reads it?

Comment: It's hard for me to believe it's a filesystem cache issue; I mean if the data is in the cache why doesn't the linker see it?  That's what a cache is for, after all.  Plus, if you can't read back data you've written, when the computer is working fine, it sort of defeats the entire purpose of a filesystem.  It could be a bug in make, where it's not waiting for all the compilations to finish before starting the link.  3.81 is >11 years out of date now so who knows?  But, it's definitely not because make sees the object file created and assumes the target is complete.

Comment: for what it's worth,  we're using ccache - don't know if this may cause issues like that? anyway, difficult to track down since it's not reproducible at all; never happened a single time to me when I was locally working on it - only once or twice on the build server after I checked the code/makefile in...

Comment: (and any instrumentation/debugging stuff I'll put into the makefile to find the reason may cause the problem to never show again anymore, since this will change the execution environment/timing)

Comment: All true.  You might consider your build server configuration if it only happens there: is it using a different type of filesystem?  Are you using NFS or NAS storage instead of a local disk?  I don't see why ccache should matter but maybe there's a bug there: are you using a similarly old version of ccache?  You can ask on their mailing lists.  Is the ccache location on the same partition as the build server or do you have to move files to a new partition to be cached?

Comment: Also you can try modifying your link line to sleep for a few seconds and retry if it fails; if that makes it work it's some kind of timing issue for sure.  If not then in some situations the object file is written out corrupted; that points to a ccache issue or filesystem issue (or a problem with the compiler/assembler itself) for sure.

Comment: was all my fault in the end...
the makefile executes in parallel as said, but those parallel invocations update the same files; i.e. while one instance created that object file and used it for linking the other instance sometimes re-created that object file at the same time - problem with modifying/adapting existing makefile where re-creation from scratch would probably have been the better approach!
now I am creating everything in instance-specific directiories, even if not needed for certain objects, and this solved the problem.